# How to continue a match in Regex

Tags: regex

```
price:(?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|min)-?(?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|max)?
```

This Regex matches the following examples correctly.

```
price:1.00-342
price:.1-23
price:4
price:min-900.00
price:.10-.50
price:45-100
price:453.23-231231
price:min-max
```

Now I want to improve it to match these cases.

```
price:4.45-8.00;10.45-14.50
price:1.00-max;3-12;23.34-12.19
price:1.00-2.50;min-12;23.34-max
```

Currently the match stops at the semi colon.  How can I get the regex to repeat across the semi-colon dividers?

**Final Solution:**

```
price:(((\d*\.)?\d+|min)-?((\d*\.)?\d+|max)?;?)+
```

Comment: We need a bit more context as to what you *don't* want to match. The regex `^.*$` will match all of the examples you've given. In general, though, you can add `;?`, create a non-capturing group around everything after "price:" and add `*`

Comment: Your regular expression also matches "price:minmax" and "price:1.2.3". Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional ; at the end, and make the whole pattern to match one or more:

`price:((?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|min)-?(?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|max)?;?)+`

Answer (score 1):

First there are some issues with your regular expression: to match xx.yyy instead of the expression `(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+` you can use this `(?:\d*\.)?\d+`. This can only match in one way so it avoids unnecessary backtracking.

Also currently your regular expression matches things like `price:minmax` and `price:1.2.3` which I assume you do not want to match.

The simple way to repeat your match is to add a semi-colon and then repeat your regular expression verbatim.

You can do it like this though to avoid writing out the entire regular twice:

```
price:(?:(?:(?:\d*\.)?\d+|min)(?:-(?:(?:\d*\.)?\d+|max))?(?:;|$))*
```

See it in action on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/kY8wfuhu7T).

Comment: Why can't he just say "or more of these"?

Comment: @zebediah49: Because there is no syntax in regular expressions for "add a separator then do the same again". :(

Comment: `(?:<something>(?:<sep>|$))+` ?

Comment: @Amber: I've totally rewritten the regular expression - I hope you'll agree that it's much cleaner (and more correct!) now. Let me know if you find further improvements.

Answer (score 1):

`(?:\d+)?` is the same thing as `\d*`, and `(?:\.)?` can just be `\.?`. Simplified, your original regex is:

```
price:(?:\d*\.?\d+|min)(?:-(?:\d*\.?\d+|max))?
```

You have two choices. You can either do `price([:;]range)*` where *range* is the regex you have for matching number ranges, or be more precise about the punctuation but have to write out *range* twice and do `price:range(;range)*`.

```
price([:;]range)*      -- shorter but allows first ':' to be ';'
price:range(;range)*   -- longer but gets colon vs semi-colon correct
```

Pick one of these two regexes:

```
price[:;](?:\d*\.?\d+|min)(?:-(?:\d*\.?\d+|max))?
price:(?:\d*\.?\d+|min)(?:-(?:\d*\.?\d+|max))?(?:(?:\d*\.?\d+|min)(?:-(?:\d*\.?\d+|max))?)*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price:((?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|min)-?(?:(?:\d+)?(?:\.)?\d+|max)?;?)+
```

I'm not sure what's up with all of the ?'s (I know the syntax, I just don't know why you're using it so much), but that should do it for you.

Comment: Just a note: For the string 'price:min-maxmax' this matches 'price:min-max' which might or might not be what the OP wants (he didn't specify).